# How to prevent a unordered_map of shared pointers from leaking?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, shared-ptr, unordered-map

I am building a console application in wich I am only using smart pointers. I made the choice to only use smart pointers to learn when to use which smart pointer. In this application, I am trying to use a state pattern to switch between the different states. The base class is TurnState from this class all the other state-classes inherit.

In the gamecontroller, I have defined the current state. For switching between the states I want to use an unordered_map with an enum as key and the state class as value. But as soon as I wrote down `std::unordered_map<TurnStateEnum, std::shared_ptr<TurnState>> _turn_states_map;` inside the header I got some memory leaks.

To get rid of those memory leaks I tried to destroy them in the deconstructor like this:

```
GameController::~GameController()
{
    for (std::unordered_map<TurnStateEnum, std::shared_ptr<TurnState>>::iterator iterator{ _turn_states_map.begin() }; iterator != _turn_states_map.end(); iterator++) {
        iterator->second.reset();
        _turn_states_map.erase(iterator);
    }
    _turn_states_map.clear();
}
```

But that did not work out either. I was able to solve it using raw pointers but that is not what I am trying to achieve. So my question is, how do I delete a map with shared_ptrs in the correct way?

All help will be appreciated.

---

#### Edit 1 - Minimal example

---

The Game Controller will be used for holding a shared_ptr to the current state and switching to the next one.

Below is the GameController header:

```
class GameController
{
public:
    GameController();
    ~GameController();
    void do_action(Socket& client, Player& player, std::string command);
    void set_next_state(TurnStateEnum state);

private:
    std::unordered_map<TurnStateEnum, std::shared_ptr<TurnState>> _turn_states_map;
    std::shared_ptr<TurnState> _turn_state;

    void initialize_turn_states_map();
};
```

Below is the GameController source:

```
GameController::GameController()
{
    initialize_turn_states_map();
    _turn_state = _turn_states_map.at(TurnStateEnum::SETUP);
}

GameController::~GameController()
{
    for (std::unordered_map<TurnStateEnum, std::shared_ptr<TurnState>>::iterator iterator{ _turn_states_map.begin() }; iterator != _turn_states_map.end(); iterator++) {
        iterator->second.reset();
        _turn_states_map.erase(iterator);
    }
    _turn_states_map.clear();
}

void GameController::do_action(Socket& client, Player& player, std::string command)
{
    _turn_state->do_turn(client, player, command);
}

void GameController::set_next_state(TurnStateEnum state)
{
    _turn_state = _turn_states_map.at(state);
}

void GameController::initialize_turn_states_map()
{
    _turn_states_map.insert(std::make_pair(TurnStateEnum::SETUP, std::make_shared<SetupState>(*this)));
}
```

The TurnState is the base class. This class should contain the current logic/behaviour of the application.
Below the TurnState header:

```
class GameController;

class TurnState
{
public:
    TurnState(GameController& gameCtrl);
    virtual ~TurnState();

    void next_state(TurnStateEnum stateEnum);
    virtual void do_turn(Socket& client, Player& player, std::string command) = 0;
protected:
    GameController& _gameCtrl;
};
```

Below the TurnState source:

```
TurnState::TurnState(GameController& gameCtrl) : _gameCtrl ( gameCtrl )
{
}

TurnState::~TurnState()
{
}

void TurnState::next_state(TurnStateEnum stateEnum)
{
    _gameCtrl.set_next_state(stateEnum);
}
```

Setup State does not have any other variables or methods than his base class and for now, the methods are empty.

---

#### Edit 2 - Minimal example v2

---

This might be a better minimal example. I created a console project and uploaded it to: https://ufile.io/ce79d

Comment: Something leaks in `TurnState` maybe?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was scared for that too. To test it I made a shared_ptr from TurnState and it did not leak, after it went out of scope it was nicely cleaned up.

Comment: How are you sure that it's this part of your code that leaks? It's very unlikely to happen from `std::unordered_map` of `std::shared_ptr`. Can you provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: Smart pointers are often advertised as a magic button to fix all memory leaks. This is far from the truth. It's true that properly using them means never having to worry about `delete`ing anything, the key word there is "properly". You must understand how smart pointers work, and how memory works, in general. The difference between automatic and dynamic scope. Circular references would be one way to leak memory, despite having smart pointers coming out of your gazoo, for example. You need to invest some time boning up with your C++ book, until you fully understand how they work, why, and how.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have edited my question, so it shows the code that is causing the problem. I also uploaded a minimal example to https://ufile.io/ce79d . I hope that it clarifies the problem that I ran into.

Comment: _@user3473161_ OK. The problem seems to turn out to having a cyclic reference [as mentioned by @Sam](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610157/how-to-prevent-a-unordered-map-of-shared-pointers-from-leaking?noredirect=1#comment72350079_42610157).

Comment: `_turn_states_map.erase(iterator)` invalidates `iterator`. Subsequent `iterator++` exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I know that smart pointers are not a magical solution and I never expected them to be. I still prefer the raw ones over the smart. But that is why I am practising with the smart pointers, to learn more about them. I know that often circular references are the cause of the leaks in code. But in haven't found any circular references in my code and I have searched for them for quite a while. And I tend to think that it is nearly impossible miss a circular references because there are not that many lines of code.

Comment: Normally if your application is built around smart pointers, your destructors should mostly be defaulted. Remove **all code** from the destructors and try again.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Could you explain to me where that cyclic reference would be? I tried to comment out all my code and only leave the gamecontroller and the map uncommented and still there were those annoying memory leaks. I have a hard time believing that it is referenced somewhere else.

Comment: @user3473161 `GameController& _gameCtrl;` in `TurnState` and `GameController` references all `TurnState`s in turn?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ So that is the problem? I thought refereces were allowed, well gues I look stupid now. Gues I am going to have to look for an other sollution to be able to use the controller in my states. Thanks for your help, atleast now I can try and look for a sollution for it. I am glad that you took the time to help me.

Comment: @user3473161 `std::weak_ptr` may come in handy for finding a solution.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Since StackOverflow does not have a chat function. I am just going to say thanks over here. After a few hours messing around with my code and looking at how to pass a weak pointer to my states without leaking, I finally did it. My state pattern works without memory leaks ^^, you have my gratitude.

Comment: @user3473161 _"Since StackOverflow does not have a chat function."_ Seems to be some caching problems right now: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3473161/user3473161

Answer (score 0):

There are no leaks in your program. You are using `std::shared_ptr` correctly. There are no circular references to fix. Although the destructors were redundant, they were harmless.

You are just not using `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` right. You are calling it before destructors for local objects in `main` are run. Naturally it will report memory allocated by these objects as leaks.

To fix:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  (
    GameController gameCtrl = GameController();
    gameCtrl.do_action("test");
  }
  _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();  

  return 0;
}
```